# How to attach disk that get destroyed when instance is shutdown using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a GCP instance and a disk that are defined like this:

```
resource google_compute_instance my_instance {
   ...
  attached_disk {
    source = "my_disk"
    device_name = "data-disk1"
    kms_key_self_link = var.kms_key_self_link
    mode = "READ_WRITE"
  }
  ....
}

resource  google_compute_region_disk my_data_disk1  {
  count = (var.master_count + ( var.master_count * var.replicas))
  provider  = google-beta
  name = "my_disk"
  project = var.service_project
  type = var.attach_data_disk_type
  region = substr(local.uk_staging_zones[count.index],0,12)
  size = var.attach_data_disk_size
  disk_encryption_key {
    kms_key_name    = var.kms_key_self_link
  }
}
```

When the VM instance is shutdown, the disk still exists. Is there anyway I can force the disk to be destroyed when the VM is shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the documentation says:

> Persistent disks are located **independently from your virtual machine instances, so you can detach or move persistent disks to keep your data even after you delete your instances**. Persistent disk performance scales automatically with size, so you can resize your existing persistent disks or add more persistent disks to an instance to meet your performance and storage space requirements.

More information in [1].

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_region_disk